# Is there a better term than ACCOUNT (as in User Account)

Tags: terminology

We are using "login" but I don't like that b/c it has a lot meanings:

- Verb (the act of logging in)
- Noun : their login ID ("what's my login"),  ID *and* password (what's my login) their entire account ("my login was deleted")

so I want to use Account, Account ID, Account Password.

**But** maybe Account isn't "human" enough.

Comment: Actually, "login" is a noun while "log in" is the verb (see http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5302/log-in-to-or-log-into-or-login-to).  Though most people won't understand there is a difference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would argue there are 3 options here for you:

1. Use the term account. It is a conventional term and, being somewhat risk adverse, always argue that is users know and understand that GUI or convention, why break from it? but I completely understand that the term "account" indicates some form of conglomerate-esque, computerized registration that may or may not be paid for. Eurgh. There are ways to get around this though by removing that perception eg. using "FREE" - see [Evernote](https://evernote.com/)
2. I've started to see lots of companies just use "sign in" and "sign up" removing that horrible "account" word perhaps for the disadvantages indicated in #1. [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/), [Square](https://squareup.com/), [ODesk](https://www.odesk.com/) the list goes on.
3. Finally, I guess you can improve the personification of the term "account". When you're logged in instead of "my account" say "Hi David" or similar (see [Ted Baker](http://www.tedbaker.com/uk/))? Or what does the account represent? For example an ecommerce site might use the term "Sign in to see your previous orders" or if it's a control panel "Sign in to your admin area" (or control panel)

So here are some things to consider:

- What does the "account" represent? More context needed, not just for
  me but for the user
- Can you include small persuasive cues such as
  "Free" or "Lifetime access" that might represent the benefits of an
  account of the ease of signing in?
- Can you add personality around
  the term "account" a la Ted Baker?
- All else fails, "account" isn't
  that bad. Users know what it is and that's what matters most.

Answer (score 3):

I think the term "user" may be appropriate here.

It can be coupled with whatever you need to describe and has a human element to it. Thus:

- User Account
- User Id
- User Login
- User Password

I realize it is just an additional modifier but if you want humanize the terminology this seems like a viable option.

Comment: can consider adding "user name" to the list.

Answer (score 0):

I quite like **persons** to refer to humans in the system, either users or the system or just contacts.

And **actors** seems to work well to refer to actual users of the system, although I don't have anything against just using the term **users** either.

Finally, another option is **agents**, which I think works for human users as well as system users, basically an alternative to using the work *accounts*.

Answer (score 0):

It also depends on the usecase of your website.

- Do users actively know that they need to have an account on your
  page, including users that don't have one yet?
- What do users log in to on your site: Do they access a core functionality?
- In that case you could make the link descriptive of the area that users are trying to reach: Dashboard, MyBank, E-mail.
- Google has a similar approach (yes, in addition to the login, but same mindset):

  [image]

Answer (score 0):

One approach that is becoming more common is to use **Sign In** and **Sign out** for the actions, and **Profile** for "all the stuff about this user".